# Border around content misaligned on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, border

I use the code below to create a border around the content background, it looks ok on desktop, but as the screen gets smaller the frame is losing its position and going over the content. Looking for a way to make that frame stick to the background color and be responsive.
Here's [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/su132raw/)

```
    <div style="position:relative;">
      <div class="bg">
       <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
       </div>
       <div>
        <a href="#">View More</a>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    body {
    background: #000;
    }

    .bg {
    background: #f90000;
    padding: 55px 20px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    }

    .bg h2 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .bg a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .bg:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 170px;
    right: 170px;
    bottom: -15px;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
    }
```

Comment: why does it need to work on all platforms?

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade Like nearly every site these days it has to be responsive, I am looking for a solution to avoid targetting media queries which is a pain in this example

Comment: Why doing it with pseudo element? I wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your borders (which are in the `after` pseudo element) are positioned in absolute but its parent is static (default `position` value). Absolute positioned elements are always relative the first none-static parent.

Set `.bg` position to relative and change your left and right properties of your `:after` so your borders will always be relative to its parent.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.bg {
  background: #f90000;
  padding: 55px 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position : relative;
}

.bg h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border: #fff 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div class="bg">
    <div>
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">View More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `position:relative` to the `.bg` class and also set `min-width` so that the frame should stick for the smaller screens

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/su132raw/3/)**

Comment: @downvoter Any reason so that I can improve my answer?

Comment: The Big Mysteries of StackOverflow.

Comment: It always has been, and will always be a big debate, but I'm siding with SO here: votes should always be anonymous. [Here's an interesting read aswell.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not) Anyway, you might agree or disagree.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt your jsfiddle doesn't seem to be correct, at least on my end. the border goes over the red background and not around it.

Comment: @Radi I think it was a misunderstanding...when I opened your fiddle, result looks like you want border over the background..thats why I set the `min-width`.....BTW updated...See updated link

Answer (score 0):

Make the width, font size, and padding relative to the width.

see:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

use the unit `vw`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you had fixed values on the `left` and `right` propreties. That meant that when the window resizes, the width of the backgronud changes, as the relative position of the borders to the window border.

So, to solve the problem use the new CSS3 `calc()` function as shown:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.bg {
  background: #f90000;
  padding: 55px 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.bg h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: calc(25% - 20px); /* Because you padding is 20px */
  right: calc(25% - 20px);
  bottom: -15px;
  border: #fff 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div class="bg">
    <div>
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">View More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```